# Dynamic Programming Find All Possible Team Combinations

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've been trying to solve a problem in wich i have to compute the number of possible team formations for a random sport.

The input is something like this:

```
P → Number of Team Players
R → Roles  
[Min, Max] → Role 0
[Min, Max] → Role 1
...
[Min, Max] → Role r-1
----------
Min= Minimum number of Players for the Role
Max= Maximum number of Players for the Role
```

---

Take for example Sport1. Let's say Sport1 as 3 types of Roles( A, B, C), now let's imagine each team has 8 players.

```
8 → Number of Team Players
3 → Roles  
[3 , 7] → Role A
[1 , 5] → Role B
[0 , 2] → Role C
```

> Valid team formations: 
>   [`3-5-0` , `3-4-1`, `3-3-2`, `4-4-0`, `4-3-1`, `4-2-2`, `5-3-0`, `5-2-1`, `5-1-2`, `6-2-0`, `6-1-1`, `7-1-0`]
>
> Number of valid Team Formations: 12

I already solved this by going at every possible formation and if the sum of players in each role is equal to the Number of Team Players then add one to the final result. Otherwise add zero a.k.a. do the same for next combination until end not reached.

3+5+0 = 8 → **valid team formation**.

3+5+1 > 8 → **invalid team formation**

3+4+0 < 8 → **invalid team formation**

---

This is all fun and games until the Number of players goes for something like 40 and the number of roles to something like 20 and the Min = 0 and Max = 40 for each role.

Example:

```
40
20
[0; 40] → Role A
[0; 40] → Role B
...
[0; 40] → Role T
```

In this case i would need to check for 40^20 possible formations for wich i already did some cuts by only doing for the role A 0 and then multiply by 20, but still need to check 40^19 different combinations.

This problem has to be solved using Dynamic Programming. I already used DP to solve some problems(sequence problems, maximum profit strawberry crates) but can't seem to find a way to solve this one.

Can somebody give some lights on how to solve this problem and/or similar problems i could find online or in a book that could lead me to find the DP solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic programming problems usually end up with you arranging the parts of a problem in a sequence so you can work through them from left to right, doing enough work at stage n so that you can refer to it for all the information at stage n+1.

Here you could think of the first n Roles as the first n stages, so the first n lines like "[Min, Max] → Role 0" in your example. At stage n I would compute, for all numbers of players available up to the maximum of P, the number of different formations you can make up using just the first n roles and up to that number of players.

At stage n+1, for each number of players available, I would consider all the legal numbers of players in role n+1. Subtracting that from the number of players I was currently considering, I get a number of players left for the first n roles and I look up the answer stored there to get the number of different formations for the first n roles. Adding these possibilities up, I get the number of formations I can make up for the first n+1 roles using that number of players in total. Clearly, I repeat this for all numbers up to P to get the answers I need to store for stage n+1 - unless this is the final stage, in which case only need the answer for P players.

If the decisions you make can be arranged left to right in stages, where the answer for each stage doesn't depend on much information and can be calculated from the answer for previous stages, then dynamic programming is usually a practical way of solving the problem. You can turn almost any problem into a dynamic programming problem, if you are prepared to store and calculate for a very large number of possibilities at each stages, but eventually this number gets so big that the so-called solution becomes quite impractical.

As an example, in the problem at the top the second stage is the following problem with just two roles, A and B.

[3 , 7] → Role A

[1 , 5] → Role B

In the original problem, you need to work out the total number of different team formations if P=8, that is, if you have 8 players in the team. The second stage problem is to work out the number of formations if there are just two roles, but you need to work out the number of formations for 0 players, for 1 players, for 2 players... up to 8 players. Then when you come to work out the answer for the third stage you can say for example "If I put 3 players in role C I have 5 players left and two roles left and I can look at the answer I have already calculated for the two-role problem with 5 players to see how many formations there are with 3 players in role C."

Comment: I'm not sure if i completly got it...
So for example with the example i gave on my question: 8 players, 3 roles...
Create something like this http://prntscr.com/6jo812 ?
Can you tell me how you would compute the first line?
Thanks

Comment: Every entry in the first line is 1, because with only one role to chose from there is only one way to allocate the available players to the available roles.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by avaliable players. For example second line i have 2 roles avaliable 0 and 1 but the number of players is the 8 from the first line + the number of players at the column i'm right now or 
first line column players + second line column players?

Comment: I have tried to add text to the end of the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks i'll read and think about it.
Edit: Can you provide the full solution for this http://prntscr.com/6jo812 ??
Maybe with the solution i can fully understand the problem.
Thanks again.

Comment: (Just noticed a mistake about the first line. If the number of available players is outside the range of the [Min, Max] setting for the only role left, there are 0 ways to produce a formation. If the number of available players is within the legal range then, yes, there are 1 ways to produce a formation.

Comment: And the other roles also calculate inside their limits or for all number of players from 0 to P?
If i'm on the second line and have 2 players i need to go get the line 1 with 6 players and sum that to 2? Can't seem to understand that part.
So in the example: 

First Line → 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
.................................................
Sec Line  → 0 ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
............

3rd  Line  → ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?

Comment: Working very hastily I seem to get 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0, 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5, 0 0 0 0 1 3 6 9 12 where of course you only need the last number for the final row. In the first row any valid number for Role A is OK. In the second row you can have 1-5 Role B and it turns out that in the range 4-8 players for Roles A and B every additional player gives you another formation. In the last row you can have 0-2 Role C so each number in this row is the sum of three adjacent numbers in the previous row starting with 0+0+1 and ending with 3+4+5.